# NSFetchedResultsController blocking UI

Tags: multithreading, core-data

I´m trying a very basic CoreData stack, namely a MOC with MainQueue concurrency type directly attached to the PSC. I´m creating 10.000 simple MO and i have a FRC that shows all entities. My UI is being blocked after the MOs were already created. Since i don´t save my MOC, hence not locking the PSC, i was expecting the UI not to block.

Where does the blocking come from? Is it just the responsability of the FRC NSFetchedResultsController loading the data?

Thank you

Comment: 1. Include some code. 2. set the fetchBatchSize to avoid loading all the results in your FRC

Comment: Heres a starter http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller